# set a caption and label in a tikz timingtable environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, tikz-timing, timing-diagrams

Is it possible to set a caption and label within a tikz timing table? Or do I have to do that somehow within a tikzpicture? 
Here the codefragment:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[xscale=1.5,yscale=1.5,timing/.cd,
        metachar={w}{z [black]},
        metachar={W}{Z [black]},
        slope=0]
      T1 & LLHLHHLH \\
      T2 & LLHHLHLH \\
      Summe & WWDDDDWD \\
      Daten & LLHHHHLH \ \extracode
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
       \foreach [count=\x] \b in {0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1} {
            \node [below,font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,inner ysep=2pt] at (\x-.5,0) {\b};
       }
       \foreach [count=\y] \b in {0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1} {
            \node [below,font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,inner ysep=2pt] at (\y-.5,-2) {\b};
       }
       \foreach [count=\z] \b in {0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1} {
            \node [below,font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,inner ysep=2pt] at (\z-.5,-6) {\b};
       }
   \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[xscale=1.5,yscale=1.5,timing/.cd,
        c/dual arrows,c/arrow tip=latex,
        c/arrow pos=.7,
        metachar={v}{[timing/c/no arrows]c[timing/c/dual arrows]},
        metachar={w}{z [black]},
        metachar={W}{Z [black]},
        slope=0]
      T1 & ccv CCC cv CC c \\
      T2 & ccv CcvCCCCc \\
      Summe & wdwDwDDdWDw \\
      Daten & ccv Ccv HH 0c0h0l 0c CCc \ \extracode
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
       \foreach [count=\x] \b in {0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1} {
            \node [below,font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,inner ysep=2pt] at (\x-.5,0) {\b};
       }
       \foreach [count=\y] \b in {0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1} {
            \node [below,font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,inner ysep=2pt] at (\y-.5,-2) {\b};
       }
       \foreach [count=\z] \b in {0,0,1,?,?,1,0,1} {
            \node [below,font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,inner ysep=2pt] at (\z-.5,-6) {\b};
       }
   \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Should the caption be a `figure`, `table` or custom caption? Should the `tikztimingtable` float or be displayed right where it is?

Comment: BTW: If you want the `Z` character (and `z`) in black you can change its style, e.g. globally using `\tikzset{timing/z/.style={black}}` or for a single `tikztimingtable` using `[timing/z/.style={black}]` as optional argument.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer (clicking the tick symbol below the voting arrows) or state what is still missing if the answer is not sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to typeset the caption outside a floating environment, you can use the `\captionof` command provided by the `caption` (or the `capt-of`) package; the first argument of the command can be `figure` or `table` (or any other floating  user-defined object), and it is used to decide which name to put into the caption label. Here's a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  ... (timing table code)
  \captionof{figure}{Here goes the caption}
  \label{fig:timetible}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Another option, would be to enclose the timing table inside one of the predefined float objects `figure` or `table` and to use the standard `\caption` command (now, of course, the timing table will be treated as a floating object):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  ...(timing table code)...
  \caption{A test timing diagram}
  \label{fig:timtable}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

A third possibility will be to define a new floating environment and caption type for the timing diagrams; this can be done with the help of a number of packages: `float`, `floatrow`, and `caption`. Here's an example using the `\DeclareCaptionType` command provided by the `caption` package (the example also illustrates the creation of a new "list of timing diagrams" similar to the list of figures and list of tables):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionType{timingdiag}[Timing diagram][List of Timing Diagrams]

\begin{document}
\listoftimingdiags

\begin{timingdiag}[!ht]
  \centering
  ... (timing table code)...
  \caption{A test timing diagram}
  \label{fig:timetible}
\end{timingdiag}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: taking into account Martin's comment, I've added some other options to my answer; which one to use will depend on the intent.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: Alright, thank you! That's what I was searching for

Comment: Might be a good idea to put something like this in manual. (I'm the author of `tikz-timing`).

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: yes, it would be a good idea.

Comment: Nice update, but I would name it 'Timing Diagram' instead.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: done.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I found this post again after almost a year ;-) I open a ticket for `tikz-timing` so that I remember adding it: https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/tikz-timing/issue/3/add-example-for-timing-diagram-captions